# $dateTrunc not working properly mongodb aggregation operator

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want all past seven day data and perform another logic on that

Sample collection:

```json
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "6493d3452846a19a72536f77"
    },
    "companyId": {
      "$oid": "64709aeae523bf2ea4696fed"
    },
    "ip": "::1",
    "timestamp": {
      "$date": "2023-06-27T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "6493d3452846a19a72536f73"
    },
    "companyId": {
      "$oid": "64709aeae523bf2ea4696fed"
    },
    "ip": "::1",
    "timestamp": {
      "$date": "2023-07-04T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
  }
]
```

Aggregation pipeline:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "subtractSevenDayFromNOW": {
        "$dateTrunc": {
          "date": "$$NOW",
          "unit": "day",
          "binSize": 7
        }
      },
      "subtractSevenDayFromTimestamp": {
        "$dateTrunc": {
          "date": "$timestamp",
          "unit": "day",
          "binSize": 7
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      timestamp: 1,
      subtractSevenDayFromNOW: 1,
      subtractSevenDayFromTimestamp: 1
    }
  },{
//match stage and another stage
}
])
```

output:

```json
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("6493d3452846a19a72536f77"),
    "subtractSevenDayFromNOW": ISODate("2023-07-01T00:00:00Z"),
    "subtractSevenDayFromTimestamp": ISODate("2023-06-24T00:00:00Z"),
    "timestamp": ISODate("2023-06-27T00:00:00Z")
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("6493d3452846a19a72536f73"),
    "subtractSevenDayFromNOW": ISODate("2023-07-01T00:00:00Z"),
    "subtractSevenDayFromTimestamp": ISODate("2023-07-01T00:00:00Z"),
    "timestamp": ISODate("2023-07-04T00:00:00Z")
  }
]
```

In output after removing 7 day from the `timestamp` it is `2023-07-01` and `2023-06-24` but i want this `2023-06-20`, `2023-06-28`

playground link : https://mongoplayground.net/p/0WI5IMWLeCt

anybody have solution of this issue?

Comment: Maybe use `$dateSubtract`?